# subprocess and call a sftp command

Tags: python, call, sftp

When I sftp to a server with this command in Linux Ubuntu:

```
sftp -b /path/sftp_put user@10.10.10.10
```

it acts correctly but when use call in my Python project like:

```
call(["sftp", "-b","/path/sftp_put",'user@10.10.10.10'])
```

it does not work and creates this error:

```
Host key verification failed.
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: May be that it is asking for a password.

Comment: Why don't you use a python sftp client like paramiko?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to a server with sftp/ssh for the first time you are usually asked to confirm server key fingerprint is correct ( this behavior can be changed in client settings )

For example:

```
ssh sftp02.domain.com
```

> The authenticity of host 'ftp02.domain.com (10.90.229.2)' can't be established.
>   ECDSA key fingerprint is 9c:4a:b3:1a:ce:a8:78:81:c6:a1:a1:8b:8f:c0:e0:27.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

You have to confirm and the key will be added to your known hosts and you will not be asked again until the server key changes. When that's the case either the server has been reinstalled, key regenerated or you are maliciously redirected to a different server.

Answer (score 0):

Since `sftp` is a specialized `ssh` command, try adding `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` as a parameter. I tried this from MacOS and it seemed to work:

> Warning: Permanently added 'sftp.example.com,1.1.1.1' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

REF: https://askubuntu.com/questions/123072/ssh-automatically-accept-keys